# openwrtにおけるクロスコンパイルエラー(アーキテクチャの間違いによるsysntax error)

Tags: linux, c, gcc, compiler

## 現環境の説明

今現在は、仮想マシン上でopenwrt用のsdkを用いてクロスコンパイルを行っています。

[OpenWRT環境で動くC言語プログラムのコンパイル方法](https://qiita.com/asuzuki2008/items/e89bd0733689a7601c08)

この方の記事を参考に実行していますが、5年以上の前の記事のため所々変えながら動かしている状況です。

変更した部分は

```
https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/OpenWrt-SDK-15.05-ar71xx-generic_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

から

https://archive.openwrt.org/releases/22.03.5/targets/ath79/generic/openwrt-sdk-22.03.5-ath79-generic_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64.tar.xz

に変更
```

その後、パスを

```
export cc=/home/****/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_24kc_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc

export STAGING_DIR=/home/****/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_24kc_gcc-11.2.0_musl
```

に変更しています。

## 起きている問題点

クロスコンパイル後のファイルをscpでコピー、実行しようとするとsysntax errorと出てきます。

```
./helloworld
./helloworld: line 0: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
root@OpenWrt:~# cat helloworld
@@@@((uu   -==X`-==8880hhhDDStd8880Ptd   44QtdRtd-==HH/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 GNUGNUypTvq!rGNUemH "d s "__cxa_finalize__libc_start_mainputslibc.so.6GLIBC_2.2.5GLIBC_2.34_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable__gmon_start___ITM_registerTMCloneTable'ui   1=@@??????H/Ht5/%/h%/D%u/D1I^HHPTE11H=S/f.H=y/Hr/H9tH6/Ht        H=I/H5B/H)HH?HHHtH/HfD=/u+UH=.HtH=.dh=oHHH]Hello World4h0@PP9zRx$4 FJ?:*3$"\tqEC
?P   oo ooo=0@GCC: (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0     3I@U=|@= = ? M @->@EhK@X g@ @Q`&@I@ "Scrt1.o__abi_tagcrtstuff.cderegister_tm_clones__do_global_dtors_auxcompleted.0__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entryframe_dummy__frame_dummy_init_array_entryhelloworld.c__FRAME_END___DYNAMIC__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE___libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTableputs@GLIBC_2.2.5_edata_fini__data_start__gmon_start____dso_handle_IO_stdin_used_end__bss_startmain__TMC_END___ITM_registerTMCloneTable__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5_init.symtab.strtab.shstrtab.interp.note.gnu.property.note.gnu.build-id.note.ABI-tag.gnu.hash.dynsym.dynstr.gnu.version.gnu.version_r.rela.dyn.rela.plt.init.plt.got.plt.sec.text.fini.rodata.eh_frame_hdr.eh_frame.init_array.fini_array.dynamic.data.bss.comment#886hh$I Wo$aiqo~o  0PPB@    4H H=-?@0@00-@0`     35root@OpenWrt:~#
```

異なるアーキテクチャでコンパイルすると、このようなエラーが出ることは知っていますが、どこで間違えているかがわかりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

## デバイス情報

```
cat cpuinfo
system type             : Atheros AR7242 rev 1
machine                 : Buffalo WZR-HP-G450H/WZR-450HP
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 24Kc V7.4
BogoMIPS                : 265.42
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 16
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes, count: 4, address/irw mask: [0x0ffc, 0x0ffc, 0x0ffb, 0x0ffb]
isa                     : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented        : mips16
Options implemented     : tlb 4kex 4k_cache prefetch mcheck ejtag llsc dc_aliases perf_cntr_intr_bit perf
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
package                 : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

[openwrtの方の情報も載せておきます](https://openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/buffalo/buffalo_wzr-hp-g450h_v1)

## 追記情報

### コンパイル時のコマンド

```
cd helloworld/
$ export cc=/home/****/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_24kc_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc
$ export STAGING_DIR=/home/****/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_24kc_gcc-11.2.0_musl

$ cc -o helloworld_.o helloworld.c
$ ls
helloworld  helloworld.c  helloworld.o  helloworld_.o
```

### fileコマンドによる確認結果

```
$ file helloworld_.o
helloworld_.o: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7970d60ea39eaa8515cd165476711a8721720092, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Comment: コンパイル時のコマンドや、生成されたファイルの情報を `file` コマンドで調べて追記してみてください。 参考 https://armadillo.atmark-techno.com/faq/not-cross-compile

Comment: コンパイルする際のコマンドとfileコマンドの実行結果を記載しました。

これはx86で実行する用のファイルであっていますか？

Comment: いますぐ試す環境が無いので詳しい回答はできませんが、https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile の手順も確認してみて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「コンパイルする際のコマンド」に誤りが有ります。

> `$ export cc=/home/...`

として変数 `cc` に代入していますが、これが使われていません。コンパイル時に

> `$ cc -o helloworld_.o helloworld.c`

としていますが、本来はこの箇所で使いたかったのではないでしょうか。つまり、

> `$ $cc -o helloworld_.o helloworld.c`

のような使い方です。参考になさっているサイトでは変数には大文字の `CC` を使っているようですね。そちらの方が間違えにくくて良いかも知れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
$ccで実行するときちんと動きました！！！！